# How to display too long text properly in WPF ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox, texttrimming

I have a ComboBox that shows text of various lengths. For texts that are not long there is not a problem. For the texts longer than the width of ComboBox I would like to trim the text and add "..." (an ellipsis) at the end to show them properly. The bottom line is that I don't want to  change the width of the ComboBox. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a custom `ItemTemplate` for your `ComboBox`, which makes use of a `TextBlock` with the `TextTrimming` property set to `CharacterEllipsis`.

Example:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="..." SelectedValuePath="...">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock 
        Text="{Binding ...}" 
        TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: The binding that exists on the Combobox previously is not working in this format

Answer (score 9):

The answer, as Ross said, is to implement a custom `ItemTemplate`. However, to make it work properly, you need to do the binding properly.

A note on this method: You cannot set both the `DisplayMemberPath` and the `ItemTemplate`, it must be one or the other.

So, for the general case where the display member is the item (such as for a string), you can use binding with no properties to bind to the `DataContext` of the template:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="..." SelectedValuePath="...">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Or, you can put it in a style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

For the case where you want to bind to a specific property of the object, similar to how you would use the `DisplayMemberPath` property, replace the binding with the binding that you would use to a property on the object that you are binding. So, replace the fourth line in my first example with something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDisplayMemberProperty}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
```

The binding is in the context of a single item of the type bound to your ComboBox. To make this more explicit, you can do the following:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:MyItemType}">
    <!-- My DataTemplate stuff here -->
</DataTemplate>
```

This will give you hints for the properties on the object while you are writing code inside the `DataTemplate`.

Comment: This answer is excellent, Lauraducky. It can be a risk to answer old questions, in case one's work appears to go unrewarded, but nevertheless a number of the 5,917+ readers of this page will have benefited from your work. Keep it up!

Comment: @halfer thank you. I certainly didn't answer out of an expectation to get lots of upvotes, hopefully this is useful to someone out there :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TextTrimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.texttrimming.aspx) `CharacterEllipsis` or `WordEllipsis` for the textblocks in your combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Also works with a more complex DataTemplate; however, I had to resort to a DockPanel instead of the standard WrapPanel.

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <DockPanel>
        <AccessText DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Icon}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
      </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```